# access database in visual basic rows delete

Tags: database, vb.net, rows, delete-row

i have this code to delete rows from a button:

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter

    con.Open()

    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from orders", con)
    da.Fill(dt)

    dt.Rows(0).BeginEdit()
    dt.Rows(0).Delete()
    dt.Rows(0).EndEdit()

    Dim cb As New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)

    da.Update(dt)

    frmCheckOut.OrdersDataGridView.DataSource = dt.DefaultView

    con.Close()
```

but it only deletes one row. how can i make this delete multiple rows?
sorry i am new in visual basic.

Comment: `dt.Rows(0).Delete()` youa re just deleting the first row.  use a loop

Comment: i have no idea on how am i going to loop this :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not too familiar with the BeginEdit() and EndEdit(), but if I was to take a guess at a solution, I would use a ForEach loop.  Whether you want to delete all rows or just rows that meet a certain condition, this is a simple way to loop through all the rows of your datatable.

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim ds As New DataSet
ds.Tables.Add(dt)
Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter

con.Open()

da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from orders", con)
da.Fill(dt)

For Each row as DataRow in dt.Rows

    ' ** IF (statement if needs to meet certain condition to delete.)

    row.BeginEdit()
    row.Delete()
    row.EndEdit()

    ' ** END IF

Next

Dim cb As New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)

da.Update(dt)

frmCheckOut.OrdersDataGridView.DataSource = dt.DefaultView

con.Close()
```